# v8 impossible to free memory allocated by context

Tags: memory-leaks, v8

v8 version: 4.7.80.25

```
Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
create_params.array_buffer_allocator = &array_buffer_allocator;

Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
Locker locker(isolate);
Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

Local<Context> ctx = Context::New(isolate);
Context::Scope context_scope(ctx);

Local<Script> script;
Local<String> name = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "wtf.js");
Local<String> source = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "var a = []; for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++) a.push(new Array(1000000).join('*'));");
ScriptOrigin origin(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "wtf.js"));

script = Script::Compile(ctx, source, &origin).ToLocalChecked();
Handle<Value> result = script->Run(ctx).ToLocalChecked();
```

After ctx goes out of the scope nothing happens, memory usage is still high
I also tried to play with storing ctx in a persistent handle and calling .Reset on it - with zero success

Memory is being freed only and only when I call isolate->Dispose()

Comment: What specific memory are you asking about?   Javascript memory is only cleaned up when the garbage collector decides to collect it.   

This depends on a few things including the memory it thinks is allocated (it won't even run if there's not much memory used), and having time to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question!

@xaxxon was absolutely right about it, v8 context won't be garbage collected immediately after it goes out of the scope.
To check it's reachability for GC I simply called `RequestGarbageCollectionForTesting` and it indeed freed the context memory

So basically there were nothing to worry about - eventually this memory will be available again.